# How can I test for AllowOverride FileInfo in Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I'm running a web site under a shared hosting environment (it's [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com), if it makes a difference) and attempting to use **SetEnv** from within a **.htaccess** file.

Everything else in the .htaccess file is working fine and Apache is not generating errors.

Since SetEnv requires **Override FileInfo** ([ref](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html)), I figure that's my problem.  I have a Perl script dumping out %ENV to test my config changes, but nothing I've tried works.

How can I **test that AllowOverride FileInfo is enabled**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for references while writing the question, I found the answer.  I figured I'd document my answer here in case anyone else has the same problem.

The SetEnv was working but the Perl script I was testing with runs under Suexec.  According to [this support document](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/CGI#Suexec), Suexec strips off all environment variables that do not begin with **HTTP_**.